# Deriving consistency of OLS estimators using Chebyshevs Inequality

Tags: multiple-regression

I am trying to apply the following proof directly to the OLS-estimator,

$P(|\bar{X}-\mu| \geq k) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}$

Using $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N} \sum X_i$ and $Var(X) = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum Var(X)$, under an i.i.d assumption.

This is pretty straight forward. However, if I want to use $\hat{\beta} = \beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\varepsilon$ and $var(\beta) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$, I run into trouble.

Assuming that all Gauss-Markov assumptions are met, how do I go ahead and prove consistency using Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: It seems your $\beta$ is a vector. Then how to define consistency for a vector estimate?

Comment: Consistency means convergence to the true values componentwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}_n(0, \sigma^2 I_n)$, then

$$
\mathbb{P}\big [ \Vert \hat{\beta}_n - \beta \Vert \geq \zeta \big ] = \mathbb{P}\big [ \sqrt{(\hat{\beta}_n - \beta )^T ( \hat{\beta}_n - \beta ) }\geq \zeta \big]
$$

Note that $\hat{\beta}_n - \beta \sim \mathcal{N}(0 , \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1})$

Thus let $U_n = (\hat{\beta}_n - \beta )^T ( \hat{\beta}_n - \beta )$ we have from Markov Inequality,

$$
\mathbb{P}\big [ \Vert \hat{\beta}_n - \beta \Vert \geq \zeta \big ] = \mathbb{P} ( U_n \geq \zeta^2 ) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(U_n)}{\zeta^2}
$$

and $\mathbb{E}(U_n) = \sigma^2\text{Trace}( (X^T X)^{-1} ) \longrightarrow 0$ (I guess, I don't have a proof for that...)

Comment: You can't possibly have a proof for that last convergence until you make assumptions about what happens with $X$ as the number of observations increases.  You are treating $X$ as if it were fixed, but in the context it looks like you have to view it as an iid sample from a random variable.

Comment: With an assumption of a correctly specified model that meets all relevant assumptions, I'd believe that $E[U_n] = \sigma^2 Trace([(X'X)^{-1}]) ---> 0$.

So, if I understand you correctly, it should be sufficient to deal with the trace of the Variance/Covariance-matrix, without using an estimator of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: If the trace converges to zero then you have the definition of the convergence in probability for $\hat{\beta}$